# How do I download only the file names of webpages using wget on Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, command-line, bash, wget

I am currently using this command:

```
wget -m https://example.org --limit-rate=25m --convert-links --timestamps --wait=0.5 --execute="robots = off"
```

And it works wonderfully. However, I would like the equivalent of downloading the file normally via wget, and then making all the files blank. Is this possible? For example, assuming that `example.org` contains `page.html`, `index.html` and `page2.html`, I would like my folder to contain:

```
index.html
page.html
page2.html
```

These files would need to be blank. Would this be possible using wget, or is there another command-line tool that can do this? I am looking for compatibility with Ubuntu or Windows. Both would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

**"Filename" isn't really a concept for web pages**, or at least not from a user's perspective. There may or may not be a static file on the server hosting your example.org/page.html, and it may or may not be named page.html.

Comment: I understand. I wish to download only the all the filenames in a directory, not a specific page's.

Comment: "Directory" isn't really a web concept either (though some web servers can make use of the concept by displaying a "directory view" of linked pages).

Comment: Ah, my bad wording again.  What I am saying is that I would like the equivalent of downloading the file normally via wget, and then making all the files blank. Is this possible?

Comment: For directory, I meant the root directory for the site.

Comment: I have finished editing my post. Please let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Hello there, can you please answer my question based on my updates? Thanks!

Comment: Hey there, it's been almost a month since I've edited my post. Can you please answer it?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are still there, but if you are, can you please answer my question? Thanks.